# Is Blake2b vulnerable to length extension attacks?

Tags: hash, length-extension, blake2

There are very few resources for Blake2b apart from the official documentation and website. I would like to know if Blake2b is not vulnerable to length extension attacks unlike SHA2. I would like your help as soon as possible.

Comment: the original BLAKE hash was a SHA3 finalist, there's no way BLAKE would make it all the way to the final round of the SHA3 competition (where it lost to Keccak) with a length extension vulnerability :)  (btw BLAKE3 might interest you: https://github.com/BLAKE3-team/BLAKE3/blob/master/README.md )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All from the BLAKE2 paper [BLAKE2: simpler, smaller, fast as MD5](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/322.pdf)

First of all

> BLAKE2b is optimized for 64-bit platforms — including NEON-enabled
> ARMs — and produces digests of any size between 1 and 64 bytes.

and from the abstract of the article

> BLAKE2 is often faster than MD5, yet provides security
> similar to that of SHA-3: up to 256-bit collision resistance, **immunity
> to length extension**, indifferentiability from a random oracle, etc

---

**The reason for the resistance to length extension attack**

The countermeasure comes from the compression function. The last parameter is set to false when the processed chunk is not the last one.

```
Compress(h, chunk, cBytesCompressed, false)
```

It is set to true when the last chunk is compressed.

```
Compress(h, chunk, cBytesCompressed, true)
```

So, if an attacker tries to extend a hash, during the recalculation the verifier will arrive in a different hash value then the attackers provided.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was under the gun all day long. I must have overlooked it when I read the paper.

Comment: It happens to all. At least you got it fast :)