# Known text attack on Hash function (SHA 256 or SHA512)

Tags: hash, sha-256, sha-512

I was thinking the below attack scenario on hash function. Let's assume that three binary numbers A(1000 bits), B(16 bits) and C(283 bits) are concatenated together and H(A||B||C) is generated using SHA256 or SHA512. Here, the attacker knows C. Knowing C, is it possible for an attacker to find A or B or (A||B) from the output H(A||B||C)? If yes, what are the attacks and how to prevent them?

Thank You.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: What actually I wanted to do is that, 1st entity wants to send H(A||B||C) to 2nd entity for integrity check. Both entity know A, B and C. but C is public so attacker also know that. So is it safe to send this H(A||B||C) where the attacker can not know about A, B or A||B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let consider $h = H(A\mathbin\|B\mathbin\|C)$ for SHA-256 or SHA-512 where both are MD-based cryptographic hash functions of NIST with

- $A$ is 1000 bits
- $B$ 16 bits, and
- $C$ 283 bits

and we further assume that the attacker knows $h$ and $C$

**Brute-force search**

Definitely, the attacker cannot test the 1016-bit of unknown data to match the $h$. Bitcoin miners, the biggest known collective entity, can reach around $\approx 2^{93}$ This road is closed.

**Prime-image attack**

To find a pre-image normally we look for the first $a2^n$ input to find an input $x$ such that $h=H(x)$. For your case a little different.

- Try random $a2^n$ values in the range $[2^{1299},2^{1300}]$. This has two problems;

  1. It is infeasible
  2. Even if the attackers have found one, the probability of result is equal to your data is $$\frac{2^{1299}}{2^{256}} = \frac{1}{2^{1043}}$$ for SHA-256, and $$\frac{2^{1299}}{2^{512}} = \frac{1}{2^{787}}$$ for SHA=512. Impractical, this road is closed, too.

And, we know that SHA-256 and SHA-512 are pre-image resistant, this road is also closed, too.

**A simple counter-argument**

- If there is an attack on your case, that is one can extract $A$ and $B$ from $H(A\mathbin\|B\mathbin\|C)$ with the knowledge of $C$, Then we can use the [length extension attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_extension_attack) on SHA-256 and SHA-512 to execute a pre-image. Simple, for a given $h'$ with $h' = SHA-256(x)$, execute a length extension $h'' = \operatorname{SHA-256}(x\mathbin\|C')$, then extract $X$ form $h''$ with the knowledge of $C'$. We don't have such any method.

  In other words, extend the hash then find a pre-image. End of the path.

---

If you are looking for a secure way to hash with a key, the obvious method is the HMAC or you can use KMAC of SHA3.

Comment: I don't understand how length extension attacks come into play. We know a length extension attack on SHA-256: If you know $H(A||B||C)$ then there is one specific $D$ for which you also know $H(A||B||C||D)$. So what? How does that matter towards finding $A||B$?

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' By considering that knowing C is a subset length extension. Then, if one can extract the information from $H(A||B||C)$ by knowing only the $C$, then take any $H(X)$ and extend it, since we know the extended part, we can extract the $X$. Not a great argument, I know.

Comment: I have a very naive question. For length extension attacks, the format is H(secret || message). But I change the format, is it still vulnerable? for example: A and B are secrets and C is the message. Then, I concatenate (A || C || B) and generate the hash H(A || C || B), will it still be vulnerable to length extension attack? If so, how?

Comment: @Sami the precious moment of the LEA is that the attacker can execute a signature without learning the key. The easiest mitigation is use SHA3, which naturally has resistance, use [Blake2](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/83208/18298) which uses the [HAIFA](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/83342/18298). Your modification is [secret suffix](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/87482/18298) is secure. Why don't you use HMAC or KMAC?