# Should I use HMAC to create a multiple part HASH token

Tags: hash, authentication, hmac, sha-256

I have a web API with a custom API authentication system that users each have a **SecretKey** and a public **ApiKey**. Using these two keys client(or user) can generate a token for the authentication on the server.

Consider this function generating an authentication token

```
public string GetToken(string apiKey, string secretKey, string expireTimestamp)
{
    using var hashAlgorithm = SHA256.Create();
    var byteValue = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(apiKey + secretKey + expireTimestamp)
    var byteHash = hashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(byteValue)
    return Convert.ToBase64String(byteHash) + expireTimestamp
}
```

So a token is a combination of

$$token = SHA256(APIKey \mathbin\| SecretKey \mathbin\| expireTimestamp) \mathbin\| expireTimestamp$$

Using this token we have a unique expirable authentication system for our APIs,

**questions:**

1. Should I concatenate keys+expTime or I should use something like HMAC?
   is this scenario vulnerable to attacks like **length extension attacks** without HMAC?
2. What is the vulnerability of this system (if there is any)?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; they have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132054/discussion-on-question-by-alireza-should-i-use-hmac-to-create-a-multiple-part-ha).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using $$token = SHA256(APIKey \mathbin\| SecretKey \mathbin\| expireTimestamp) \mathbin\| expireTimestamp$$

is not secure since it can cause a length extension attack as;

$$token2 = SHA256(APIKey \mathbin\| SecretKey \mathbin\| expireTimestamp \| \color{red}{extension}) \mathbin\| (expireTimestamp \| \color{red}{extension}) $$

This is a valid token for the forgery.

NIST on call to SHA3 candidates required to be [resistant to length-extension
attacks](https://web.archive.org/web/20170821222702/http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/hash/documents/FR_Notice_Nov07.pdf). Keccak now named SHA3 as the winner and Blake2 is still a good alternative from the competition. Both are resistant to length extension attacks, Keccak by using the capacity and Blake2 is using [HAIFA](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/83343/18298) construction, are secure to length extension attacks.

To mitiage one can use HMAC;

$$token = \operatorname{HMAC-SHA256}(privateKey, publicKey \mathbin\| expireTimestamp) \mathbin\| expireTimestamp$$ Note that this will call the SHA-256 at least two times ( three times if the key is longer than the block size of the hash function, 512-bit for SHA-256).

Instead of HMAC, we can use BLAKE2. BLAKE2 is very fast and even we have a parallel version [BLAKE3](https://github.com/BLAKE3-team/BLAKE3) and using

$$token = \operatorname{BLAKE2}( publicKey \mathbin\| privateKey  \mathbin\|expireTimestamp) \mathbin\| expireTimestamp$$ is secure.

NIST also standardized a MAC for SHA3 named [KMAC](https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/sp/800-185/final)( or [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/95723/18298)).

Both BLAKE2 and KMAC are preferable to HMAC.

If you insist to use SHA2 with a 256-bit output size then use SHA-512/256 which is the truncated version of SHA-512/256 with different initial values to separate the domains. SHA-512/256 is immune to length extension attacks and it is 64-bit CPU friendly by design.

Comment: thank you @kelalaka, this really helps.  your example with the `extension` created another question for me, What if all 3 part has a fixed length always. 
e.g (apikey=36, privateKey=44, expireTime=10). 
Is SHA256 vulnerable in this case or not. because `expireTime` has a fixed length no one can add a extension to it

Comment: If you know the sizes and check them, then there is no longer an extension attack as long as the attacker doesn't trick that part too. I would go a length extension attack secure one to eliminate attack surfaces.

Comment: Note; I've updated the answer to include the SHA-512/256 that you may want to use.